# Django Rest Framework nested list serialization

Tags: django-rest-framework

It probably is a bad design. In my viewset, I returned some nested list like :

`[<Para: Para object (59)>, <Para: Para object (60)>, <Para: Para object (61)>, <Para: Para object (62)>, <Para: Para object (63)>, <Para: Para object (64)>, <Para: Para object (65)>, [<Para: Para object (66)>, <Para: Para object (67)>]]`

It is a nested list. The parent of the inner list is another object.

Is there any way to serialize this list? Or it just against the spirit of Restful API?

I want the output JSON be like:

```
{
{*para object},
{*para object},
[{*para object},{*para object}],
{*para object}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: From your description I'm not entirely sure this is what you need to look into, but what you're looking for might be the serialization of [nested relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I overrided the list method in Viewset. For each item in queryset, if it is an object then serialize it with model serializer, if it is an list then call it self.

Finally, return such serialized list. Check Below:

```
Class aViewSet(...):
    serializer_class = ParaSerializers

    def  list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()

        return  Response(self.serilalizeNestList(queryset))

    def serilalizeNestList(self,array):
        result = []
        for item in array:
            if isinstance(item,list):
                result.append(self.serilalizeNestList(item))
            else:
                data = self.get_serializer(item).data
                result.append(data)
        return result
```

Comment: Correct me if I did some wrong here. Or if it has a performance issue. Thank you.